# jQuery event handler not working properly?

Tags: jquery

Again I'm asking this question, but now I had this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EHGLU/ created for it. And something else it's going on too.

If I test it on localhost, when I click the create button, I first get the message in the console and then I get redirected to the `#` action. Why is this happening ?

And in the fiddle, instead of getting the same behavior as Rollback button, I get some string of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is submitting to #

```
<form name="rollback-form" id="backup-03-02-2012" class="rollback-form" method="post" action="#">
```

Do this to not submit the form normally after you ajax stuff.

```
$(backup).on('click', create,function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Yes, but why isn't the other one behaving the same ?

Comment: After `return false;` or before ? Because If I put it at the bottom of the `.on` function, the same stuff happens, I get redirected, if I put it at the beginning only the console works, but the rest not.

Comment: You can see here the result with your suggestion : http://jsfiddle.net/EHGLU/1/ ; At my end still doesn't work, the rest of the code doesn't get executed.

Comment: I changed your backup click event to act like your rollback event and I removed the ability for the form to actually submit, so now it is just using ajax http://jsfiddle.net/EHGLU/2/

Comment: And now I'm back to square one, the page keeps resubmitting. What you should get when clicking the Backup button is the same thing as hitting the Rollback one, which is a fade in of `Error | Check PHP log for information`, but you don't. So after I applied your solution with `.preventDefault` it didn't redirect to the `#` action, but the Ajax didn't work. Since yesterday I keep trying everything I can think of, and I tested on other laptops too, yet the same result.

Comment: You're going to have to go through line by line and make sure you understand what is happening. Use your browsers developer tools to step through line by line.